# An objects coordinates relating to a frame on a timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, coordinates, timeline

To anybody who may care to help:

I am looking to create an animation (perhaps frame by frame) that corresponds with the coordinates of an object. Specifically, I want to have a draggable object's coordinates (locked to the x-axis) indicate where the playhead of a specific movie clip should be.

In other words, let's say that I have a 100px wide stage and I want each px location of an object on that stage to correspond to a particular frame of a movieclip.

In concept, I feel that it should be as easy as loading an objects coordinates into a variable, then passing that variable on with a simple math equation, adjusting it for movieclip length... but right about then my brain gets fried.

Finding out how to lock a draggable object to the x-axis has been pretty easy, but from there I'm stumped. I'm not particularly well versed in AS3 but I do like to think I understand the concepts.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of movie clip are you playing? Like is it an external swf or a MovieClip object? Do you know the number of frames that it has?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import flash.events.Event;

//the min (left-most) coord your draggable mc can be dragged 
var  minX:int=0;

//the max (right-most) coord your draggable mc can be dragged 
var maxX:int=100;

var frameTo:uint;

//enterframe listener to check drag_mc x position continuously
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe_handler);

function enterframe_handler(e:Event):void
{
  //drag_mc is your draggable movieclip, anim_mc is the animation
  //drag_mc.x should always be between minX and maxX: (minX <= drag_mc.x <= maxX)
  //(drag_mc.x/(maxX - minX) gives us the "percentage" (from 0 to 1)
  //multiply by the animation's total frames lenght,
  // and add 1 (because frame numbers begin at 1)
  frameTo  =  1 + Math.floor((drag_mc.x/(maxX - minX))* anim_mc.totalFrames);

  //set animation to target frame!
  anim_mc.gotoAndStop(frameTo);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like it ought to work, however, what seems to be happening is that once it compiles, it's looking at where drag_mc is presently and goes to the corresponding frame in anim_mc. Moving drag_mc isn't affecting anim_mc after the initial load. I'm going to keep tooling with it but if this seems like a simple fix, I'm all ears.

Comment: you should put the last bit of code in an enterframe listener to keep checking the positioning of drag_mc. I'll fix the code example to show this.